# css tricks to shorten my redundant code

Tags: html, css

I have an html that look like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/blue_background.png" class ="menu-bg"/>
    <a href="#" class="menu-portal"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/blue_background.png" class ="menu-bg"/>
    <a href="#" class="menu-tags"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/blue_background.png" class ="menu-bg"/>
    <a href="#" class="menu-requests"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/blue_background.png" class ="menu-bg"/>
    <a href="#" class="menu-videos"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see the code above I kept repeating my blue background which in element `img`. Can anyone help me shorten this up. For example if I can insert the `img` in my `li` element, that would do.

Any help will be great.

Comment: did you try `background-image`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use it as a background, instead a defining a separate image tag.

```
ul li { 
   background-image: url("assets/images/blue_background.png");
   height: 30px; /* height of the image */
   width: 30px; /* width of the image if the size is fixed */
}
```

Comment: There's no real reason to nest `li` under `ul` in the selector. Further, you should use a class for this, lest all `li`s get the background.

Comment: @PetrMarek That doesn't mean it shouldn't be added!

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, `ul` in my example is more of symbolic representation of a parent ;)